# Interface или abstract class

Tags: java

Насколько я знаю интерфейс с одной из недавних версий могут иметь реализацию по умолчанию, отсюда вопрос зачем нужны абстрактные классы, если они теперь лишены своего преимущества, но имеют ограничения в наследовании в отличии от интерфейсов

Comment: Интерфейсы и абстрактные классы -- это принципиально разные вещи. Интерфейс задает поведение, а абстрактный класс -- это фундамент, который задает иерархию.

Comment: Вы для себя должны чётко разделять такие понятия ООП как абстрактные классы и интерфейсы, И использовать по назначению. А то что можно реализовывать методы, так это чисто фишка джавы. К тому же лучше углубиться и понять для чего эта фишка добавлена, как пример поддержка стримов текущими коллекциями

Answer (score 1):

В абстрактном классе можно делать поля экземпляра, чего нельзя делать в интерфейсах. Зачем нужны? Риторический вопрос, я вот лично терпеть не могу абстрактные классы. Но вот на работе постоянно сталкиваюсь с ними.

Answer (score 1):

Абстрактные классы используются там, где можно выделить иерархию и единый функционал для подклассов.

То есть зачастую в абстрактном классе описываются методы (часто с protected модификатором доступа), которые доступны только дочерним классам и устраняют дублирование кода в подклассах или же реализуют метод интерфейса по умолчанию.

Один из ярких примеров библиотека Swing для Java:

Есть интерфейс [TableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html), который имеет 9 методов для реализации.
Все 9 методов обычному программисту может быть ненужно реализовывать, для этого разработчики вводят абстрактный класс, который так и называется [AbstractTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html), который уже реализует некоторые методы по умолчанию, таким образом, программисту вместо реализации всех методов из интерфейса, достаточно наследовать класс и описать только нужные ему методы.
Более того, разработчики Swing пошли дальше и создали класс [DefaultTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html), который вообще реализует весь функционал и программисту остается только переопределить методы. которые необходимы для его конкретной задачи.